# Diff the undo command

Tags: vim

Is there any simple way to see a diff between the current state of the file and the state that it would be if I were to `u` once? Sometimes I would like to see what the last change was (especially when I'm not sure what I pressed) but a simple blink-test (`u` and `^r`) isn't making the last change obvious.

I could probably perform an undo, then write it to another buffer, then revert the undo, then `vimdiff` the buffers. However I am hoping that something simpler exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) plugin and [Gundo - Visualize your undo tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) (requires Python) can do that. It'll show the undo points on the left side and a diff of the last undo in a bottom window.